# 3d objects that disappear in my scene when rendering using cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, filmic-blender

I'm creating a small scene, which is my bedroom, and following is the problem i'm facing

[image]

This bed that shows in preview mode just disappears in cycle render

[image]

Only the feet remain.
These two objects are cubes with these modifiers applied to

[image]

[image]

the material applied is the Following:
the only change between the two is the color

[image]

i use an hdri combined with a directional light pointing to a point in space that i can move,

The camera is rigged with constraints on a location point and a look at point

I'll appreciate any help of any kind, best regards,

Comment: Maybe they are disabled for rendering. Check their visibility in their object property panel.

Comment: i Don't think that's this, in the visiblity tab they are marked as visible in viewports and renders

Comment: and their collection?

Comment: the collection is also marked as visible

Comment: Show images ot the outliner

Comment: sorry I don't understand @susu

Comment: ... just "eye" symbol in the outliner ? In the outliner, right click on the collection and look at the visibility part of the menu

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but by looking at the eye symbol the visibility is checked, but I've tried to disable the modifiers on one of the cube and it appeared back so I think it's modifier faults

Comment: There is 3 "type of" visibility... even if unsure this is your issu, look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRZzz.jpg

Comment: well it appear to be the smooth modifier rather than visiblity, i'll investigate to make it appear with the smooth.

Comment: ok, get it: sudivision is set to 0 for render... so smooth is smoothing too far at 27

Comment: Thanks! I've set it to 6 to render it worked, I didn't realized there was a render parameter in this modifier, I'm sorry I used your time for such little thing

Comment: @LouisBERTRAND, il n'y a pas de mal!

Comment: héhé, vraiment merci en tout cas @lemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the answer to the problem i had:

after conversing with @lemon , he/she as found a the answer.

Regarding the modifiers i was appliying, the subdivision surface modifier was set to 0 for the render as you can see in the image.

[image]

So, the smooth modifier was smothing a mesh that has to few vertices to be seen on screen.